# code for extracting numbers outside parenthesis doesn't work

Tags: c++

I'm trying to write a simple program that extracts the numbers and operands outside the last pair of parenthesis, i'm trying to achieve this by employing a simple recursive function, however, my code is printing nothing. What's wrong with the code?

```
class Puller{
    private:
    std::vector<std::string> container;
    std::string cache;
    public:
    void sep(std::string x, int y){
        if(x[y] != '('){
            cache.push_back(x[y]);
            sep(x,y + 1);
        }
        else if(x[y] == '('){
            container.push_back(cache);
            cache.clear();
            sep(x,y + 1);
        }
        else if(x[y] == ')'){
            cache.clear();
            sep(x,y + 1);
        }
        else if(x[y] == NULL){
            container.push_back(cache);
        }
    }
    void show(){
        for(auto i : container){
            std::cout<<"Radicals: "<<i<<'\n';
        }
    }
};
int main(int argc, char** argv){
    const std::string str = "100+(2*3+4)*2";
    Puller larry;
    larry.sep(str,0);
    larry.show();
}
```

Comment: The recursion never stops.

Comment: Your `!='('` defeats all other elseifs apart from the first, i.e. it is impossible that they ever trigger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with the wrong stopping condition which is leading to an infinite recursion in this line `if(x[y] != '('){`. You just need to put that condition in the end or you can ignore it all.

```
   void sep(std::string x, int y){ 
        if(x[y] == '('){
            container.push_back(cache);
            cache.clear();
            sep(x,y + 1);
        }
        else if(x[y] == ')'){
            cache.clear();
            sep(x,y + 1);
        }
        else if(x[y] == NULL) {
            container.push_back(cache);
        }
        else if(x[y] != '('){ // if can be omitted
            cache.push_back(x[y]);
            sep(x,y + 1);
        }
    }
```